svg sprite eating aria-hidden attribute
I am using svg sprite but our site is using AudioEye to do accessibility validation and all the svgs are marked as being a high level error because they don't have an accessible name.
The easiest way to handle it seems to me to put an aria hidden on the svg - like so
<svg aria-hidden="true" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
.... paths in here
</svg>

but when the svg sprite gets built the aria-hidden attribute is not found. I suppose I need to have a way to specify attributes to copy over or add in the configuration
"shape": {
        "id": {
            "generator": "ec-%s"
        },
        "transform": [
            {
                "svgo": {
                    "plugins": [{ "convertColors": { "currentColor": true } }]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "svg": {
        "xmlDeclaration": false,
         "rootAttributes": {"aria-hidden": "true"}
    },

but aria-hidden attribute does not come out on the children svgs of the parent svg that wraps them, and it doesn't come out on the parent svg either!
Personally what i would like is for the attributes I put on every svg file would get copied to the output.
